# convert MH_EXECUTE to MH_DYLIB (mach-o)

Tags: ios, reverse, dylib, mach-o

#### The problem:

I have 2 MH_EXECUTE iOS binary files (compiled, no source code).
Lets name them `binary1` and `binary2`.
I try to switch between them before `UIApplicationMain` is called!

#### 1 try

I successfully do this with `binary1` and one `dylib`. So I try to convert MH_EXECUTE to MH_DYLIB.

---

**step 1**
creating iOS Application `binary1`

```
#import <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    NSLog(@"binary1 -> Hello, World!");

    void *handle = dlopen([[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"binary2" ofType:nil] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], RTLD_NOW);

    if (handle)
    {
        NSLog(@"DLOPEN is OK!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"!OK ... --> %s", dlerror());

    }

    return 0;
}
```

creating iOS Application `binary2`

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    NSLog(@"binary2 -> Hello, World!");

    return 0;
}
```

When I run `binary1` I get:

[image]

#### step 2

---

Lets see the difference MH_EXECUTE vs MH_DYLIB

[fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcU0s.png)
[image]

- as we can see the main difference here is File Type: MH_EXECUTE vs MH_DYLIB

Lets change them and run `binary1` again.
After change the result was `out of address space`

#### step 3

---

Lets see Load Commands
[fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEgpj.png)
[image]
* in `dylib` there is NO `__PAGEZERO` segment
* `dylib` `__TEXT` segment `VM address` == 0 but in `binary2` == 0000000100000000

So lets patch them too ... (patched: `__TEXT`, `___DATA` and `__LINKEDIT`)
After run `binary1` i get `malformed mach-o image: segment __PAGEZERO overlaps load commands`

#### step 4

---

I successfully removed `__PAGEZERO` from Load Commands now binary looks like dylib:
[fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gXS3.jpg)
[image]

But on start `binary1` I get `BAD_ACCESS`

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Subtype: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000001019e0010
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x0000000120016d78 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 892
1   dyld                            0x0000000120016c24 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 552
2   dyld                            0x0000000120010c8c ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 132
3   dyld                            0x000000012001039c ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 176
4   dyld                            0x00000001200088e0 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 180
5   dyld                            0x000000012000df68 dlopen + 684
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194e65b94 dlopen + 68
7   binary1                         0x00000001000b7e18 main (main.m:16)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194e66a04 start + 0
```

#### Any idea ???

Answer (score 7):

You're getting `BAD_ACCESS` because you removed `__PAGEZERO` and thus invalidated the rebasing opcodes. Keep __PAGEZERO but nullify it. I similarly converted an executable into a shared library and it's loading fine on iOS and macOS.

Comment: What do you mean by "nullify it"? If you zero out the VM address or size then the other segments will be misaligned.